# finding the last common directory in a jar file

Tags: jar

Is there a way to extract the last common directory structure in a jar file ?
For example,

```
jar -tf test.jar

META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/
com/a/
com/a/b/
com/a/b/c/
com/a/b/c/file1.class
com/a/b/d/
com/a/b/d/file2.class
Manifest.txt
```

The last common directory structure would be

```
com/a/b
```

I can code something in java/bash to just split by / and see if there is anything common with the next string, but I was wondering if there is a magical jar option that will save me some time.